# CDI Can't inject FirefoxDriver (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, cdi

I'm trying to use CDI to inject firefox when i need it (Avoiding to always configure the driver). But i'm always getting `NullPointer`.

I created a **producer** for the firefox driver

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FirefoxDriverProducer {

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    public FirefoxDriver getDriver() {

        // Inicia o Firefox pelo Selenium
        String caminhoFirefox = "/usr/bin/firefox";
        String profileFirefox = "Selenium";

        // Aponta o caminho para o firefox
        File pathToBinary = new File(caminhoFirefox);
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);

        // Profile que precisa ser criado no firefox
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile(profileFirefox);

        // Proxy
        String PROXY = "companyproxy:8080";
        org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, myprofile, cap);

        return driver;
    }

    public void close(@Disposes FirefoxDriver driver) {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

And when i want to use it i call it like this:

```
@Inject
private FirefoxDriver driver;
```

Like any other object i would like to inject.
But i'm always getting `NullPointer`, when i try to debug the driver it is always null, by placing a breakpoint inside the producer method `getDriver()` it's not even being called...

On the same project i've already done something similar, with `FacesContext` and `NavigationHandler`, they both worked fine.

ps: I'm running Wildfly 8, and `beans.xml` is on my web-inf.

ps2: The reason why i'm doing this is because i need to access another company site and download some information from time to time, since they don't provide no web service or anything else, only through web browser.

ps3: If i don't use CDI and take all the code from the producer and put it on the class i'm calling it works fine. So i'm assuming that it's not a problem with Selenium

The stack tracer:

```
16:48:29,632 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-43) #{testeBean.teste()}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{testeBean.teste()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.DownloadCsr.<init>(DownloadCsr.java:49) [classes:]
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.TesteBean.teste(TesteBean.java:24) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 34 more

16:48:29,642 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-43) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.DownloadCsr.<init>(DownloadCsr.java:49)
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.TesteBean.teste(TesteBean.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 34 more
```

@Edit

My `Download` class, where i have the `FireFoxDriver` injected:

```
public class DownloadCsr {

    @Inject
    private FirefoxDriver driver;

    public DownloadCsr(String usuario, String senha, LocalDateTime dataInicial,
            LocalDateTime dataFinal) throws LoginException {

        driver.get("https://companysite.net");

        // Encontra o elemento para inserir o usuario
        WebElement webUsuario = getElementByLocator(By.name("USER"), driver);
        // Insere o usuario
        webUsuario.sendKeys(usuario);

        // Encontra o elemento para inserir a senha
        WebElement webSenha = getElementByLocator(By.name("PASSWORD"), driver);
        // Insere a senha
        webSenha.sendKeys(senha);

        // Acha o bot�o de login e clica
        WebElement button = getElementByLocator(By.name("IMAGE1"), driver);
        button.click();

        // Confere se logou na pagina verificando o titulo dela, do contrario
        // lança a exceção
        if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Business Home")) {
            throw new LoginException("Can't reach the loged-in page");
        }

    }
```

For testing i'm using the following.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TesteBean implements Serializable {

    public void teste() {
        LocalDateTime dataInicial = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
        LocalDateTime dataFinal = LocalDateTime.now();

        try {
            new DownloadCsr("login", "password",
                    dataInicial, dataFinal);
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give part of the code of the bean injecting the FirefoxDriver. And give use detail on how you call this bean?

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand added both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `DownloadCsr` is not a bean. It has a constructor with parameters and you instantiate it in your class `TesteBean`. To get the CDI feature you have to let the CDI container instantiate the beans for you and provide all needed information as other injectable bean. In other word : using new give you an unmanaged an uninjected instance.

It's also a bad practice to put business code in a constructor. Constructor should contains only initialisation code. During constructor none of the field are injected yet so even if your `DownloadCsr` met requirement to be bean you would have a NPE in your constructor.

What you could do is something like that:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TesteBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private DownloadCsr dcsr;

  public void teste() {
    LocalDateTime dataInicial = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
    LocalDateTime dataFinal = LocalDateTime.now();

    try {
        dcsr.crawl("login","password", dataInicial, dataFinal);
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

with the following `DownloadCsr`

```
public class DownloadCsr {

  @Inject
  private FirefoxDriver driver;

  public void crawl(String usuario, String senha, LocalDateTime dataInicial,
        LocalDateTime dataFinal) throws LoginException {

    driver.get("https://companysite.net");

    // Encontra o elemento para inserir o usuario
    WebElement webUsuario = getElementByLocator(By.name("USER"), driver);
    // Insere o usuario
    webUsuario.sendKeys(usuario);

    // Encontra o elemento para inserir a senha
    WebElement webSenha = getElementByLocator(By.name("PASSWORD"), driver);
    // Insere a senha
    webSenha.sendKeys(senha);

    // Acha o boto de login e clica
    WebElement button = getElementByLocator(By.name("IMAGE1"), driver);
    button.click();

    // Confere se logou na pagina verificando o titulo dela, do contrario
    // lança a exceção
    if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Business Home")) {
        throw new LoginException("Can't reach the loged-in page");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I see, if i make the DownloadCsr class a bean, and don't use it with JSF only to maintain those methods and make the injection possible, would it be a bad practice?
My goal is to schedule the download method to be run everyday, but i would also have other methods that will use the Firefox driver, would it be a good practice to use a bean for that?

Comment: Yes. It's better to have your batch not triggered from the front. You could use JavaBatch or make your bean an EJB with a timeout or use Deltaspike schedule module to manage the schedule.